# Django: How forward-compatible is model_instance._myrelatedmodel_cache

Tags: django, documentation

I am currently using the "Pythonic-join technique" as documented here: [Disqus Scaling Presentation](http://ontwik.com/python/disqus-scaling-the-world%E2%80%99s-largest-django-application/) and [django-patterns-part-2-efficient-reverse-lookups blogpost](http://blog.roseman.org.uk/2010/01/11/django-patterns-part-2-efficient-reverse-lookups/). This is a fairly common technique to avoid N+1 queries, along side with `select_related`.

However, I am unable to find the official documentation of `model_instance._myrelatedmodel_cache`. My concern is if indeed this is an undocumented feature, deprecation could be a future issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an undocumented feature and as such, is vulnerable to being changed or removed in future versions of the framework without notice.  Since it isn't part of the public API, you don't have the guarantee of the Django deprecation process, either, so all bets are off.

However, if you stick with you current version (almost certainly including security-oriented point releases), your code will continue to work fine.  If you end up using this technique and want to upgrade later, you'll just have to test a bit to make sure that bit of the framework didn't change, and I'd suspect that that bit of the framework in particular isn't hugely likely to.

In the long run, life will probably be easier if you stick with documented features, but sometimes the trade-offs for speed or functionality are worth the trouble--you'll have to make that call in the context of your project.